# modulus operand in ruby compared to php

Tags: php, ruby

I'm looking for a simple explanation for how Ruby's modulo operand works and why, in Ruby

```
puts  4 % 3   # 1
puts -4 % 3   # 2 <--why?
puts -4 % -3  # -1
```

but in PHP:

```
<?php

echo  4 % 3;  #  1
echo -4 % 3;  # -1
echo -4 % -3; # -1
```

Looks to me like -4 % 3 is actally 8 % 3 (8 being the difference between 4 and -4).

Comment: The behavior of X % Y, where either X or Y are negative is a design choice (which may be "undefined behavior"). Nothing more, nothing less. This section on [integer division](http://www.davidflanagan.com/2006/06/integer-division-and-negative-numbers.html) and comments may lead to more insights. IIRC the reason for this "odd behavior" in Ruby is discussed on the ML.

Comment: If Ruby does things one way, and PHP does things another, assume that Ruby is doing it the right way! j/k

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They can both be considered correct, depending on your definition.  If `a % n == r`, then it should hold that:

```
a == q*n + r
```

where `q == a / n`.

Whether `r` is positive or negative is determined by the value of `q`.  So in your example, either of:

```
-4 == -1*3 + (-1)   // PHP
-4 == -2*3 + 2      // Ruby
```

To put it another way, the definition of `%` depends on the definition of `/`.

See also the table here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_operator#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation.  You'll see that this varies substantially between various programming languages.

Comment: Ah, this made it click for me: "definition of % depends on the definition of /". Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Here's a snippet](http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&lpg=PA45&ots=fIBlzg2siE&dq=the%20ruby%20programming%20language%20modulus&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false) on the topic from [The Ruby Programming Language](http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&dq=the%20ruby%20programming%20language), by Matz and David Flanagan.

> When one (but not both) of the operands is negative, Ruby performs the
>   integer division and modulo operations differently than languages like
>   C, C++, and Java do (but the same as the languages Python and Tcl). 
>   Consider the quotient -7/3.  Ruby rounds toward negative infinity and
>   returns -3.  C and related languages round toward zero instead and
>   return -2.  In Ruby, -a/b equals a/-b but my not equal -(a/b).
>
> Ruby's definition of the module operation also differs from that of C
>   and Java.  In Ruby, -7%3 is 2.  In C and Java, the result is -1
>   instead.  The magnitude of the result differs, because the quotient
>   differed.  But the sign of the result differs, too.  In Ruby, the sign
>   of the result is always the sign of the second operand.  In C and
>   Java, the sign of the result is always the sign of the first operand. 
>   (Ruby's remainder method behaves like the C modulo operator.)

Answer (score 1):

It actually boils down to the implementation of the language's integer casting/rounding. Since the actual equation is:

```
a - (n * int(a/n))
```

It is the `int(a/n)` portion of the equation that differs. If `a == -4` and `n == 3`, PHP will return -1, while Ruby will produce -2. Now the equation looks like this in Ruby:

```
-4 - (3 * -2)
```

and this in PHP

```
-4 - (3 * -1)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4+mod+3), 2 is correct.

edit: Seems you should be asking why PHP works that way?

edit2: PHP defines it as the remainder from the devision A/B.  Whether you consider it a bug, wrong, or a different way of doing things is up to you, I suppose.  Personally, I go for the first 2.

Comment: I'm asking about the difference, not which is correct, so I guess I am asking why PHP works that way. Any thoughts?